# why document.querySelectorAll does not work after being assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript

why document.querySelectorAll does not work after being assigned to a variable?

[image]

Comment: The `.bind()` solution in the duplicate is unfortunate because you don't always want to select from the `document`. Instead, make a function that will accept one or two arguments. If only one, it should be a string and should select from `document`. If two, the first argument should be the context and the second is the selector string.

Comment: ...`function qsa(ctx, sel) { if (typeof ctx === "string") { sel = ctx; ctx = document } return ctx.querySelectorAll(sel) }` Then you can pass a string or an element and a string. `qsa("li")` or `qsa(myElemCtx, "li")`

Answer (score 4):

Since are no longer calling it in the context of `document`, you have changed the value of `this` inside the function.

The function depends on the value of `this` being `document` to work.

If you explicitly set the value of `this`, then it works:

```js
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll;
console.log(qsa.call(document, "li").length);
```

```html
<ul><li>.<li>.<li>.</ul>
```

Comment: So `qsa.call(document,'li')` should be fine.

Comment: Regarding the answer, if u want direct thisContext, It'd also be appropriate to bind querySelectorAll with thisContext.

Comment: Our he could use `var qsa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)`